# Fail2ban SSH MaxStartups how to ban?

Tags: ssh, sshd, fail2ban

my SFTP-Server with fail2ban and UFW is running well. But now I recognized that it seems that IP-adresses are not banned when there connection is dropped by "past MaxStartups".
My auth.log looks like
Feb 26 23:19:42 SFTPSERVER sshd[2719]: drop connection #10 from [1xx.1xx.xx.xx]:57970 on [xx.xx.xx.xx]:22 past MaxStartups

In the fail2ban.log there is no entry for that ip. So it seems that this logentry is not filtered by fail2ban. How can I add a filter for this log entry? Do I have to add some regex to the sshd.conf in filter.d of my fail2ban folder?

Comment: This question may be better suited for Unix&Linux or Server Fault since it is not so much about programming as it is about sysadmin and networking.

Answer (score 0):

MaxStartups can hit anyone, i.e. it's the maximum amount of unauthenticated connections (from ALL sources, combined) before the SSH daemon will kill any new ones, until some of those unauthenticated connections have dropped.
So, Fail2Ban not banning on those, is correct... (else, it might ban you, before you even had a chance to authenticate...)

Comment: This is not quite accurate. In fact, MaxStartups being triggered actually provides attackers a very convenient way to DoSing a server. Even background noise will hit this limit in some cases. All that is needed is getting sufficient SSH connections opened over time. Using fail2ban should provide an effective way of blocking these attacks to the extent they originate from the same sources, freeing up startups for actual users.

Answer (score 0):

### Enable more fail2ban rules:

Banning IP addresses bases on being "past MaxStartups" would be quite random and it is not implemented for that reason.

Rather, consider banning IP's that contribute to MaxStartups counters while not being covered by the default fail2ban rules. The rules are typically located in:

```
/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf
```

Specifically, look for rules that match the term 'preauth' - those are not included in defaults since they are not conclusively attacks (it could be you trying to connect but the network failed just at that time). They do however significantly contribute to your MaxStartups counter as they commonly dangle for a long time before timing out or similar. If your ban is not too aggressive, you might want to include those by uncommenting them.

### Other strategies:

- Increase MaxStartups and just allow that background noise to consume a bit of your resources
- Change your SSH port to drastically reduce background noise (troublesome for many apps, though)
- Set IP filters in your firewall to limit sources allowed to connect to SSH
- Use port knocking (this practically reduces SSH use to your own though)